# Does rolling average help reduce generalize linear model on timeseries variable to OLS?

Tags: regression, time-series, generalized-linear-model, central-limit-theorem

I have a data $Y_t$ that basically measures the number of certain events at any day, and I have a time-series for all countries from 2015 to now. And I am trying to fit that $Y_t$ to some $X_t$ that I have and also add a dummy for country variable (also thinking of doing random/fixed effect for country but greater the country usually means more the event counts). I try to use some GLM like poisson or zero-inflated poisson but the result isn't too promising and smaller countries usually have lot of days where no events happening and make lot noise to the day (the fitted coefficients do not make sense). And then I do a 30-day rolling average of the event count, and do an OLS, and the model coefficients do make sense. I want seek some suggestions on if this is correct.

So the reason is basically that each day your realized $Y_t$ is akin to a sample estimate of the poisson parameter, and taking rolling mean definitely helps with that because it becomes normally distribution by CLT. I know it make your date autocorrelated but at least you get the coefficients correct or I can do something like resample by month and then do the OLS. What are some caveats to this approach?

Comment: On the face of it, your results look like they arise from your method and not the data: the rolling averages are so strongly autocorrelated that OLS is inappropriate.  Might I suggest you change your question from "is this a good idea?" to describing what you have, what you aim to do, and asking for suggestions about how to achieve that.